# Only load link from <iframe> when mouse is hovering over

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I use the following bit of code for a template I append in my index.html. The issue is that I have thousands of `<td>`'s that gets appended in a loop. And I have a feeling that when I append all of this it loads the http://en.wikipedia.org for all the `<td>`'s before actually hovering over the link. This is obviously not a usable solution as it takes hours, if not days, to load up the page. I had to kill the site when I tried.  Is there a way to set `<iframe>` so it ONLY loads the page when hovering over it?

```
template += " <td>";
template += "<a target='_blank' href="+entry['insta_url']+" style='display:block;'>";
template += entry['id'];
template += "</a>";
template += "<div class='box'><iframe src='http://en.wikipedia.org/' width = '500px' height = '500px'></iframe></div>";
template += "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the `<iframe>`'s `src` attribute, then capture, via JavaScript, the `mouseover` event, and set the `src` when the event fires.

Comment: In this example I used http://en.wikipedia.org. But I used that purely as an example. Each <td> has a unique url. I am not sure how to get it unless I can grab it from the  "<a target='_blank' href="+entry['insta_url']+" style='display:block;'>"; with a mouseover event.

the entry['insta_url] is the link.